# How to search nearby data with geocoder and other search tool?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, geo

I am using `geocoder` ruby gem in a Rails project. Now want to get nearby location search result. The search gem is using `nazrin` which operate `CloudSearch` on AWS. So the following way is what I tried:

```
City.near([39.905, 116.39139], 10).search.size(20).start(1).query('Hotel').execute
```

It doesn't work. It returned all the results but not nearby the location(`[39.905, 116.39139]`) which pointed.

It seems that `near([39.905, 116.39139], 10)` didn't fit the search method after it. But if use `Spot.near([39.905, 116.39139], 10)` itself, can get data nearby [39.905, 116.39139].

So, how to use them together?

Comment: first load the results of near by then search from that result

Comment: @Vishal I can get near by result. But when tried to search from it like `near_result.search...`, got same result as not nearby.

Comment: What exact nearby data you wants to find ?

Comment: @CryptexTechnologies Find data where nearby location.

Comment: You're using cloudsearch, not mysql? What is `[mysql]` tag doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Map API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670,151.1957&radius=500&types=food&key=API_KEY

To find the nearby location by location types. for example in the above api types=food. This will gives the all the nearby hotels, food stores etc within 500 meter radius.

Comment: If you want to search public data, sure. Won't work if you're trying to filter your own objects.